# Fastest way to copy an array - Does it have something questionable?

Tags: c, performance

When working with arrays of the same length, consider creating a structure which only contains an array so that it is easier to copy the array by simply copying the structure into another one.

The definition and declaration of the structure would be like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char array[X]; /* X is an arbitrary constant */
} Array;

Array array1;
```

Then, perform the copy by simply doing:

```
Array array2;
array2 = array1;
```

I have found that this as the fastest way of copying an array. Does it have any disadvantage?

**Edit:** X is an arbitrary constant, let's say 10. The array is not a variable length array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine, but since `X` must be defined at compile-time it is rather inflexible. You can get the same performance over an array of any length by using `memcpy` instead. In fact, compilers will usually translate `array2 = array1` into a call to `memcpy`.

---

As mentioned in the comments, whether direct assignment gets translated into a `memcpy` call depends on the size of the array amongst other compiler heuristics.

Comment: The array is not a VLA. I have tested it and this method is way faster than using memcpy (in microseconds).

Comment: @PALEN : That is compiler dependent.  If your compiler can't optimize memcpy then memcpy will be slower.  Memcpy with a fixed length should act the same way as setting array1 = array2.

Comment: @johnnycrash Agreed. Still, this way of copying assures that it will be the fastest independently of the compiler (in case it doesn't optimize as it happened to me) right?

Comment: memcpy is used even on non-VLA arrays, although only when the data to copy is larger than a certain size. If your X is only 10 then it probably doesn't switch to using memcpy. Your benchmarking confirms this.

Comment: @PALEN: Did you have optimizations on when you timed it?

Comment: @PALEN The compiler might have more and stricter type information with the direct assignment compared to memcpy, so it could potentially optimize better. Or a better compiler could have the same information in either case. Performance at this level is not really portable since you're optimizing for the nuances of your particular compiler.

Comment: @WilburVandrsmith Suppose I leave the code with the direct assignment. As it is now, and considering performance portability, it will be optimized or in the worst case, it will be translated to memcpy. So it will be faster or at least, equal to using memcpy. It can't be worse, right?

Comment: @PALEN Yes, on any practical platform direct assignment will almost certainly be the fastest method.

Answer (score 2):

X may be arbitrary (up until the limits of your compile environment), but it's (naturally) the same number for all objects of type `Array`. If you need many arrays of same length and type to be copied to each other, there's nothing inherently wrong about this, although accessing these arrays might be more cumbersome than usual.

```
Array array1;
array1.array[0] // to access the first element
```

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely dependent on the compiler and level of optimizations you use.  The compiler "should" reduce it to memcpy with a constant size, which should in turn be reduced to whatever machine specific operations exist for copying various size blocks of memory.  Small blocks should be highly machine specific these days.  Actually calling the memcpy library function to copy 4 bytes would be so "10 years ago."

With optimizations off all performance bets are off.

Comment: Ironically, gcc will sometimes replace a loop which should "ripple" a constant 7 bytes through an array with an actual call to `memmove`.